Adding Percentages to Plotly Sunburst Plot Hover Tooltip - plotly.express
Trying to customize the hover data for a plotly express sunburst plot. Been scratching my head on this one a while, trying to comb the documentation but not coming up with quite what I want. I see the post on adding percentages to the text info on the graph, but I am having trouble adding them to the hover data instead. How can we move these percentages from "label" to "hover"? I see documentation for updating plotly.graph_objects plots, but not for plotly.express.
Here is code I have so far:
if results:   
    #Build dataframe for sunburst from grouped results
    universities = [] ; groups = [] ; counts =[]
    for result in results:
        universities.append(result[0])
        groups.append(result[1])
        counts.append(result[2])
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        dict(Universities=universities, Groups=groups, Counts=counts)
    )

    fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['Universities', 'Groups'], values='Counts', hover_name="Universities")
    
    ## Can't quite get the hover info as desired. 
    ## Want University, Group (if applicable, won't apply to inner level), and percentage 
    fig.update_traces(hovertemplate = "University: %{parent}: <br>Group: %{label} </br>Count:%{value} </br>Percentage:%{percent parent}")
    fig.update_traces(textinfo="label+percent parent")
        
    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)

Here is what the above produces:

And commenting out the first fig.update_traces(...) line:

Also, is there a way to specify a different hovertemplate for the inner level vs. the outer level(s)?

Think I found the answer to the second question, at least, that is how to differentiate hovertemplates for specific parts of the graph... and unfortunately it looks like it can't be done. see here

For the first question, you need to replace %{percent parent} with %{percentParent} in hovertemplate. The template string has access to variables currentPath, root, entry, percentRoot, percentEntry and percentParent.

This is what I needed @EricLavault, for the first part at least... thanks!
